# Angularjs: assigning min value to text box

Tags: jsp, angularjs, angularjs-directive

I am new to angularjs, my requirement is that the text box should have min value as 10 and if user enters a value less than 10 then as soon as he focus on the other text box (here Name text box) the value should be changed to 10 again. I tried so far but cannot think of more, please help, sorry for wrong english and acceptance criteria:

```
<div ng-app=""><form name="myForm" ng-controller="Ctrl">Number: <input type="text" name="input" ng-model="value"
               min="10" max="500" required> Name: <input type="text" name="name" ng-model=""
               required>

<span class="error" ng-show="myForm.input.$error.required">
  Required!</span>
<span class="error" ng-show="myForm.input.$error.number">
  Not valid number!</span>
```

```
function Ctrl($scope) {$scope.value ;}
```

Answer (score 1):

Instead of resetting the value you should consider using a simple validation error message, defined by the [input[number]](http://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng.directive%3ainput.number) which has it's own attributes for handling min/max values.

Otherwise, user would assume that there's something wrong/buggy with your text field once it starts resetting the value without a notice.

Answer (score 0):

You need to use ng-change directive. Something like following.

```
<input type="text" name="name" ng-model="" ng-change="update()"  required>
```

Comment: update() is your javaScript method in which you will check the value if it is less than 10 than revert is